# WebSockets setup questions

Tags: web, socket, html5

I'm running a Windows 2008 server, and I need some help setting up whatever I need to set up on the server side.

I've been googling like mad, but with my luck, I just cant find a windows compatible server solution for setting up a WebSocket server thing. (I'm not sure what to call it. Basically what ever program is run on the server that WebSocket communications pass through)

I've had some vague experience in setting up networking systems, but I'm certainly no pro.

Anyways, here is what I need exactly:
Where I can go to download a windows server WebSockets "server thing".
How to set it up so that web sockets code can communicate with it. (EG: Where do I go to enter port/host info, and if I do) (EG2: Any required steps to take for setup)

Thanks for any help!

Cheers -- G

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have mis-understood WebSockets. It's and standard API which may be implemented in a server or client. Please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am pretty sure that there is something that must be installed on the connected web server for WebSockets to function properly. I just need some help finding one for windows 7, and on configuring it.

Comment: are you sure the port is open across firewalls and such-like that your WebSocket application is listening on?